# Some question on SERVO MOTOR

Tags: microcontroller, motor, circuit-analysis, pwm, servo

Basically we give a PWM wave to the control input, but what will be the input for the error detector...?
How is this PWM wave converted to some voltage value that can be compared from the potentiometer output....?
What is the average value of the current drawn by the servo motor, is it same as that of the dc motor...?
Can we use the DC motor drivers to drive servo motor or is there any other drivers specifically for servos....?

**Why do we give PWM wave as the control input, why not some analog value to define the position of the Spine....?**

Comment: RC Servo Motors have Geared DC Motors with Pot Feedback. PWM with specific on-off time is given to Servo so that it would stop at specified position.

Comment: yes, but why do we give PWM only why not a analog voltage..?  is there any specific reason for that...?

Comment: It's a method to run DC motors efficiently with controllers, I suppose.  PWM is like giving power to a motor for a particular time and average voltage of PWM wave is by changing the duty cycle. What do you mean by Analog voltage?

Comment: what I meant by analog voltage was some voltage value between 0v-5v....  In servo motor I think the error detector circuit is a differential amplifier for which 2 inputs are given 1:the feedback input from position sensor(potentiometer) 2:the control input signal(which is not a PWM wave, I suppose. bcoz a diffential amplifier cannot compare PWM wave with some voltage value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How is this PWM wave converted to some voltage value that can be compared from the potentiometer output....?**

It's not.

In the simplest version of the servo's position control, the servo output shaft drives a potentiometer, which is the control resistor in a monostable pulse generator. The monostable is triggered on the leading edge of the incoming command pulse. The servo loop works to make this internal feedback pulse the same length as the incoming position command pulse.

How?

If the feedback pulse ends first, a positive charging current is routed into a capacitor, and switched off when the control pulse finishes. If the control pulse ends first, the same thing happens but using a negative current.

In this way, the capacitor ends up with a voltage on it of a polarity that represents the direction of the shaft position error, the size of the voltage matching the size of the error. This is used to drive the motor control loop. The input to the control loop is of course zero when the pulses are the same length as each other.

Comment: Thank You @Neil_UK....    I got to know the exact working of SERVO now..... I will be happy if you can answer my later 2 questions also.....

Comment: @ManojCS 1.)  When position feedback sensing and control circuitry is added to a motor, the combination is called a servo motor. The motor itself in the servo *is* a normal DC motor, unless you have some fancy e.g. brushless servo. 2.) The DC motor driver is part of the servo, you don't need any external driver. If you wish to design your own servo from scratch, *then* you need a full bridge motor driver and a control IC.

Comment: So I can give the output of microcontroller directly to servo motor..... Thank you @jms

Comment: @ManojCS Yes, you can.

Answer (score 3):

PWM control of the setpoint is specific to hobby radio controlled products. Servo motors are ubiquitous in a wide range of e.g. automation, vehiclular and consumer electronics applications, but they do not generally use the RC PWM protocol.

[image]
This scheme of signalling the servo setpoint was chosen over its simplicity and ease of multiplexing multiple channels for transmission over a radio link. The first multi-channel proportional transmitters were produced at the end of the 1960's, when integrated circuits were generally not available, so simplicity was key for low cost and compact size.

Transmitting the setpoint as the amplitude of an amplitude modulated carrier would have allowed to send the equivalent of a voltage. There would have been several drawbacks, however:

- Sending multiple channels over the same radio signal would have been difficult. The receiver and transmitter could have switched between channels in sync, but it would have required complex timing circuitry and a channel sequencer in both the receiver and transmitter.
- Sending the position as a signal amplitude would have been quite prone to interference, and all nonlinearities in the transmitter and receiver circuits would have affected the response of the servo to the stick position.
- All receiver outputs would have required sample and hold circuitry, in order to keep the voltage constant when other channels are being received.

The PWM approach elegantly solved most of these issues. The transmitter combines the separate channels into a single combined pulse position modulation (CPPM) signal, where the distance of several constant width pulses from each other encode the servo setpoints. The order of the pulses determines which pulse corresponds to which channel and the channel sequence is restarted with a special synchronisation pulse after all channels have been sent.

[image]

This scheme has several advantages:

- The receiver doesn't need complex timing circuitry, since most of the timing is cleverly part of the CPPM signal. The receiver only requires a single astable timer for detecting the sync pulse and a channel sequencer. Simplicity was important when the receiver was built from discrete transistors and had to fit in a model aircraft.
- Only two signal levels need to be transmitted, so simple amplifiers can be used without fear of distortion, interference is less critical and the data can be RF modulated with plain on-off keying.
- No sample and hold is needed by in the receiver.

Comment: edit in my comments about how the servo closes its control loop by turning its position into the length of a pulse, and turning the back edge timing difference into a voltage, and I'll delete my answer and upvote yours, can't compete with your diagrams ;-)

Comment: @Neil_UK My answer doesn't address how analog servos work at all, so your answer is not redundant by any means. In fact I didn't know and hadn't yet researched how they work, your explanation makes sense. I don't think multiple answers detract from the site, and you even finished your answer first.